Application Gateway NSG rules for a deny all
I'm trying to put a deny all rule in for my Application Gateway, but it's saying I'm not allowing internet traffic on ports 65200-65535.
If I allow internet to all, works fine, but I don't want to do that.
As per the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-probe-overview#NSG%20considerations), I'm allowing those ports to my subnet.
Subnets:-
Gateway - 10.0.126.0/27
Private - 10.0.126.32/27
NSG Rules



Priority
Name
Port
Protocol
Source
Destination
Action




100
allow_gw_monitoring
65200-65535
Any
Internet
Any
Allow


110
allow_internet_to_gw
80,443
Tcp
Internet
10.0.126.0/27
Allow


120
allow_LB_inbound
6390
Tcp
AzureLoadBalancer
10.0.127.0/26
Allow


140
AllowGWManagerInbound
65200-65535
Any
GatewayManager
Any
Allow


150
DenyAnyCustomAnyInbound
Any
Any
Any
Any
Deny



